# Merging lists containing different objects using lambda function

Tags: c#, list, function, lambda

I have three different `List<string>`s of equal length that contain different kinds of data. For example:

```
List<string> dates = new List<string>() { "20120301", "20120401", "20120501", "20120601", "20120701"};
List<string> times = new List<string>() { "0500", "0800", "0100", "1800", "2100" };
List<string> quantities = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "1", "3", "1" };
```

The actual data could be anything, but the lists always have the same length. I want to merge them into a single `List<DTQ>`.

```
public struct DTQ
{
    DateTime dt;
    double q;
    public DTQ(DateTime dt, double q) { this.dt = dt; this.q = q; }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with lambda functions? So far I've managed to create a lambda function that describes how I would map the data if it were three `strings` instead of `List<string>`s:

```
Func<string, string, string, DTQ> mergeFields = (d, t, q)
            => new DTQ(DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0}{1}", d, t), "yyyyMMddhhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(q));
```

I'm not sure where I can go from there, though. The idea is to apply this function to every index of the lists.

Comment: How do you want to map them?

Comment: The first entry should be (2012 Mar 01 05:00, 1). The second entry should be (2012 Apr 01 08:00, 2). And so on, for five entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a job for [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx), except that you have 3 lists instead of 2.

Using your current definition of `mergeFields`, you could do something like that:

```
var dateAndTimes = dates.Zip(times, (d, t) => new { Date = d, Time = t });
var all = dateAndTimes.Zip(quantities, (dt, q) => new { dt.Date, dt.Time, Quantity = q });
var result = all.Select(x => mergeFields(x.Date, x.Time, x.Quantity)).ToList();
```

If you want a more generic solution, you could also create an overload of `Zip` that takes 3 collections:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    IEnumerable<TThird> third,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return first.Zip(second, (f, s) => new { f, s })
                .Zip(third, (fs, t) => resultSelector(fs.f, fs.s, t));
}
```

(alternatively, you can use Romoku's implementation which is probably a little faster)

And then use it like this:

```
var result = dates.Zip(times, quantities, mergeFields).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice answer! Never have seen Zip in action ;)

Comment: Awesome, this worked just fine. I will  try the other answer, but I don't know if I need it, since I only need to use this in one place in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the double zip but that is inefficient. Here is an extension method to zip three enumerables.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
        IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
        IEnumerable<TThird> third,
        Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TResult> resultSelector )
    {
        if( first == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "first cannot be null" );
        if( second == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "second cannot be null" );
        if( third == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "third cannot be null" );
        if(resultSelector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "resultSelector cannot be null" );

        using ( var iterator1 = first.GetEnumerator() )
        using ( var iterator2 = second.GetEnumerator() )
        using ( var iterator3 = third.GetEnumerator() )
        {
            while ( iterator1.MoveNext() && iterator2.MoveNext() && iterator3.MoveNext() )
            {
                yield return resultSelector(
                    iterator1.Current,
                    iterator2.Current,
                    iterator3.Current );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = dates.Zip(times, quantities, mergeFields);
```

Comment: Why are you saying it's "inefficient"? Have you profiled it? Obviously your solution is more efficient, but I don't think it makes a very noticeable difference...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque The two zip solution requires an intermediate object to hold the results.

Comment: Yes, but the difference is probably not that big... anyway, +1 because strictly speaking, your implementation is probably better ;)

Comment: Duplicate answer? Thomas already provided some extension method that does the same.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque There is a 175% difference on my machine assuming I did the math right. [Test Code](https://gist.github.com/Romoku/5348034)

Comment: The yield return is a good way. You should probably check for "array length of the three input arrays is the same"

Comment: @Romoku Well, the percent difference isn't all that important because both operations are just so very fast.  Unless you're zipping really, really huge data sets many times, the absolute time difference should be very small.

Comment: It'll stop when it hits the end of the shortest enumerable.

Comment: @Servy You are correct since it probably doesn't matter all that much. I just like efficient code.

Comment: @Romoku, actually your test is not significant, because you're never enumerating the results of ZipOne and ZipTwo... If you do (e.g. by calling Count on the results), running it even once is very, very long... (still running on my machine after several minutes)

Comment: @Romoku Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque You're right. I updated the code to call ToList(). There is only a ~16% difference now.

Comment: @Romoku, I also made a few changes to the tests ([here](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/5348142)). The difference is between 3% and 5% now ;). (see the comments for the changes I made)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque ~7% difference on my machine. Not bad.